# Connection refused even when all daemons are working on hadoop,

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, hadoop2

I am working on hadoop 2.X , on which when I run jps, it shows all the daemons running correctly.

```
[root@localhost Flume]# jps
3521 NodeManager
3058 DataNode
3252 SecondaryNameNode
4501 Jps
3419 ResourceManager
2957 NameNode
```

But when I run,

```
hadoop dfs -ls /
```

It says,

```
ls: Call From localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

please help me with it.

Comment: `For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`?

Comment: Follow the steps as mentioned in the link `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

Answer (score 0):

The command you gave "hadoop dfs -ls /" is not correct. Change the dfs to fs. This command can be specified in two ways:

1. hadoop fs -ls /      /* this is the old style and is deprecated */
2. hdfs dfs -ls /       /* this is the new style */

Note the difference in both commands. The 2nd part of 1st command should be fs and not dfs.